# Why is the ternary operator faster then .get for dicts?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I discovered something surprising recently. Given a dict `d` that does not contain the key `k`, using the ternary operator to attempt to retrieve an item with a default return:

```
>>> def tern():
...     d[k] if k in d else 'foo'
...
>>> timeit.timeit(tern, number=1000000)
0.12342095375061035
```

runs faster than the dict's `.get()` function:

```
>>> def get_meth():
...     d.get(k, 'foo')
...
>>> timeit.timeit(get_meth, number=1000000)
0.20549297332763672
```

This seems counter-intuitive to me. I would think that the ternary operator would require 2 searches through the dict (once to test `k in d`), then another to retrieve `d[k]`, while `.get` would simply attempt to retrieve `d[k]`, and if it fails, return `'foo'`.

I ran this on both a large dict (one million elements) and a small one (100), and both times, ternary was significantly faster.  What's going on behind the scenes here?

Comment: How often are you hitting `else`?

Comment: "Given a dict `d` that does not contain the key `k`", so every time

Comment: Given that the key is never in the dict in your test, the `d[k]` part of your ternary expression is never executed.  So only one lookup is done in either case.  The rest is that there _is_ another dict lookup in `d.get()`:  the attribute "get" has to be looked up in the dict containing `d`'s methods.

Comment: Ah! that's a good point. I imagine that `get` would be faster if the item WAS present. Lets try that

Comment: Set `m = d.get` and change the body of function to `m(k, 'foo')`, you'll see a big difference

Comment: ok, interesting result: both setting `m=d.get` AND running with the item present both still have ternary outperforming `get`

Answer (score 3):

If you disassemble the two methods, you will see that `get` has an extra `CALL_FUNCTION` which is expensive in python, compared to a `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` instruction.

**if in**

```
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('blub')
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (d)
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       22
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (d)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 ('blub')
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             19 JUMP_FORWARD             3 (to 25)
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               2 ('foo')
        >>   25 POP_TOP             
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

**Get Method:**

```
  6           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (d)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (get)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('blub')
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('foo')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2          #Expensive call
             15 POP_TOP             
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

There is a very long article I've read a while ago, which has a section that describes why `CALL_FUNCTION` is so expensive:
https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/

Comment: If the object's `__contains__` wasn't implemented in C (I'm guessing dict's is?) would the `COMPARE_OP...` be similar in cost?